# How to customize Wi-Fi on Xubuntu 12.04 to work with auto DHCP?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, xubuntu

A few days ago I've installed on my laptop Xubuntu 12.04. I had some problems with Wi-Fi, I've solved it installing correct driver. After that Wi-Fi on the laptop has started working. I connected to the W-Fi router and customized connection. In Network manager I see that I obtain DNS and other configs, but in `/etc/resolv.conf` I don't have needed nameservers.

How can I customize Wi-Fi on Xubuntu 12.04 to work with auto DHCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the settings of the router. I used the following IP address: 10.0.0.0. When I changed the IP address to 192.168.1.1, everything worked.